# Linq Grouping - aggregate, outside of a group by

Tags: sql, linq, group-by, linq-group

I've got a SQL query, that works as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    Max(Table_ID) as Max_ID, 
Col1,
Col2,
Col3,
COUNT(*) AS Occurences
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3
ORDER BY Occurences DESC
```

How can I write an identical Linq query?

The issue is, that as soon as I apply my grouping, I cannot access the non-grouped columns **Table_ID** in my case.

```
var errors = from r in MyTable
    group e by new {e.Col1, e.Col2} into g
    orderby g.Count() descending
    select new {MaxId = ???, Count =  g.Count(), g.Key.Col1, g.Key.Col2};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `g.Max(x => x.TableID)`:

```
var errors = from r in MyTable
    group e by new {e.Col1, e.Col2} into g
    orderby g.Count() descending
    select new {MaxId = g.Max(x => x.TableID), 
                Count =  g.Count(), g.Key.Col1, g.Key.Col2};
```

(Assuming you want the maximum within each group, of course.)

Comment: Ahhh, cheers mate. I tried that originally, but intelisense spazzed out at me, so I assumed what i was doing was wrong. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Jon's answer is good, I just want to elaborate a little on why:

> The issue is, that as soon as i apply my grouping, I cannot access the non-grouped columns

r went out of scope... why is that?

The two ways of ending a query are `select` or `group by` clauses.  When you add the query continuation clause `into g` to the `group by`, you are saying - the top level elements of the query are `g` and all variables introduced in the query up to this point are removed from scope.

If you search [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) for the word **splice**, you can see samples.

Don't confuse this use of `into` with `join on equals into`, which is a group join, not a query continuation.  Group join does not remove previous variables from scope.